# Python threading. Why are the threads blocking on each other?

Tags: python

```
import threading
import time

def someMethod(x):
    time.sleep(20)
    print(x);

def someMethod2(x):
    time.sleep(1)
    print(x);

t1 = threading.Thread(name="t1", target=someMethod(1));
t2 = threading.Thread(name="t2", target=someMethod2(2));

t1.start();
t2.start();
```

I'd expect the output to be 2 followed by 1 but it is 1 followed by 2. Total time is 21 seconds. How can I make it run in parallel so the output is 2 followed by 1 and both threads run in parallel so the total time is 20 units?

Comment: Apparently you called `someMethod` twice? Or was it for the sake of example?

Comment: Updated was a bug

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You called the functions *in the main thread* and passed their *return values* as the thread entry point (since they both returned `None`, this meant a no-op entry point), you didn't actually run them in separate threads. You also called `someMethod` twice, and never called `someMethod2`. To fix, change to:

```
t1 = threading.Thread(name="t1", target=someMethod, args=(1,))
t2 = threading.Thread(name="t2", target=someMethod2, args=(2,))
```

which properly passes references to the functions themselves as the entry points, with the arguments to be used, deferring execution until the thread is actually launched.